# How to show all received array result from input array value in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter

Hi I'm working in codeigniter. I want to show all array passed from an input into my email html format. But now only show 1 item name only, how to show all the item name. Thank you

```
 <?php  

    $details = $this->transaction_detail->get_all_by_header($trans->id)->result();

    foreach($details as $value)
                                {
                                echo '<input type="hidden" name="itemname" value="'. $this->item->get_info($value->item_id)->name. '">';
                                }

    ?>
```

Received the array and put into email function

```
public function send_mail()
{

    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";


    $from_email = "info@xxx.com";
    $to_email = $this->input->post('email');


// Only show one item only, how to show all the result array item name

    $itemname = $this->input->post('itemname');

    $html = "Item Name :" .  $itemname . "<br>" .




    //Load email library
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from($from_email, 'xxx.com');
    $this->email->to($to_email);
    $this->email->subject("xxx.com - Completed Order");
    $this->email->message($html);

    //Send mail


    if ($this->email->send()) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent", "Email sent successfully.");
        redirect(site_url('transactions'));
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent", "Error in sending Email.");
        return false;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess hows your app working, but first, I would make your input an array.

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="itemname[]" value="'. $this->item->get_info($value->item_id)->name. '">';
```

And then correct controller a little:

```
$html = '';
$items = $this->input->post('itemname[]');//or without square brackets
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $html .= "Item Name :" .  $item. "<br>" .
}
```

Comment: $htmli = '';
        $items = $this->input->post('itemname');//or without square brackets
        foreach ($items as $item) {
              $htmli .= "<ul><li>" .  $item. "</li></ul>";
        }

Comment: Glad it helped.